# WatchDog and Voltage control did not work microcontroller[AVR128DB48 Curiosity Nano]

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller, avr, watchdog

Hi I'm using Watchdog to control LED lights. the microcontroller is connected to laptop with a cable. Input to the microcontroller is 5V. now on the pins there is one pin `PB2` which is `5V` directly connected to the input. I want to do that if I remove that 5V female-to-male wire from `PB2` the LED turn off. when I plug in again with `PB2` it the light turn on after that the watchdog called and turn red light off after every 4 sec

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <avr/wdt.h>
#define WDTO_4S 8


void fun_red(){
        PORTB.IN=0x04; // PB2 as input
        PORTB.DIR=0x09; // PB0 and PB3 output
        
    
    PORTB.OUTCLR=0x00; // Green
    PORTB.OUTSET=0x01;
        
        
        wdt_enable(WDTO_4S);
        do 
        {
            if (PORTB.IN)
            {
                PORTB.OUTCLR=0x00; // red
            }
            else{
                PORTB.OUTSET=0x08;
            }
            

        
        } while(1);
        wdt_reset();

}

int main(void)
{
    fun_red();
}
```

Comment: You'll never get to `wdt_reset()`. Also, why are you defining `#define WDTO_4S 8`? You should be using macros from `<avr/wdt.h>`.

Comment: Also, it's not clear to me why you're using the watchdog at all.

Comment: @ThomasJager i want to watch the led for 4 second turn the red light and after that make the voltage low and turn it off

Comment: @ThomasJager I'm using AVR128DB48 Curiosity Nano

Comment: A watchdog isn't going to turn off your device, it's more going to reset it (though details may vary). If `WDTO_4S` isn't already defined in the header, don't expect to be able to use it. The watchdog is the wrong tool here.

Comment: can you gave me some short example how can I solve this problem @ThomasJager

Comment: Not an example, but I'd suggest looking at the features of the microcontroller, and the built-in libraries for using timers.

Comment: None of this makes any sense & I don't even know what you are trying to do. If you are trying to use the watchdog for the purpose of implementing application functionality, then that is a very bad idea which you should forget.

Comment: _" It's not working as I want."_ - so what does it do?  What role are you expecting the watchdog to play in this?  I would imagine that this code loops doing nothing useful until the watchdog times-out and resets the processor and starts again -so fast you won't even notice - that's what watchdog timers do. `PORTB.OUTCLR=0x00` will do nothing.  The value you assign to `OUTCLR` tells it which pin to set low - you are telling it "no pins".  There is no "_wait for watchdog_" in this code - what does that even mean.  You need to be clearer in your explanation of what you want this code to do.

Comment: @Clifford I edit the question can you check it now. sorry for my bad English. I'm not native speaker.

Comment: while the watchdog timer is a timer and can sometimes be used as a timer in a crude way if that is ultimately what you want to use it for.  use a different timer first.

Comment: what a wdt is normally used for is that if the code hangs or crashes for the set amount of time the wdt resets the part so that you for the most part boot from scratch (not uncommon for sram to be left in the prior state making it usable as a crude timer, but not normally what you want it for).   you kick the wdt at faster than that rate "Im not broken"..."im not broken" to keep it from resetting you.   Is this anywhere within the desired use case?

Comment: it sounds like you want to have a state change on a gpio pin cause an led to come on for four seconds?  first you need to learn how to turn the led on and off which maybe you have.  then you need to use a regular timer to count to four seconds.  then you learn how to blink the timer on and off for some number of seconds, then you learn how to read the gpio in put (and maybe have the led reflect the state of the input pin)(all of these are separate programs that you do one at a time not all as one thing).

Comment: then you combine all of this and poll the input (dont get into interrupts yet please).  and when it changes state, then sample the timer or start the timer, turn the led on, wait for the timer to tell you some amount of time, turn the led off stop the timer go back to polling the input pin.

Comment: what you wrote is enable the wdt, if the input is in one state then turn the led on if not turn it off, such that the led will reflect the state of the button, realtime.   then when the wdt fires the mcu resets and goes right back into this mirror the button with the led loop, possibly imperceptable when the reset happens, this is not what your description is.   the wdt is doing nothing for the program as written.  this program simply mirrors the state of the input to the output led in realtime

Comment: as stated above the reset never gets executed

Comment: @old_timer can you gave me short example that how can I compare that the voltage on this pin is 5V so it turn on the LED if I removed the watchdog. I'll set the timer manually I have an idea how to do that but how can I compare the voltage on a pin

Comment: if you need to know a specific range of voltages you need to use an ADC that supports that range.  We assume when you say 5V you mean high vs low or gnd.  Or lets just assume you mean when you read the gpio input for that pin you get a 1.  Which I didnt look at this part and those registers but the assumption was that you were doing that correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so in the edit it seems that you are wish to use PB2 as an input to control the LED on PB3 - is that correct?

You should not think in terms of voltages, these are digital I/O they have a high state and a low state and a threshold between the two.  The inputs on your part will go high at anything above 0.8 volts.  However removing the input voltage by disconnecting the wire will have no effect if you have enabled the internal pull-up, and if you have not, it will float and may not trigger a logic 0 (zero).

You either need an external pull-down resistor, or you enable the internal pull-up and invert the logic - i.e. LED on when the input is low, and LED off when input is high.  Then instead of connecting PB2 to 5V you connect it to GND.  Removing the GND connection will cause the logic state to become 1 because of the internal-pull up.  Moreover this is much safer as it avoids any risk of applying excessive voltage to the input and damaging the processor.

Given your apparent lack of knowledge of electronics, I would ask also how you have connected the LED.  You should have a current limiting series resistor and have the LED connected the correct way around.

It remains unclear what the purpose of the watchdog is in this.  It serves no purpose, but if you enable it you must maintain it to prevent the processor resetting.  The purpose of a watchdog is to reset the processor if the software stops running normally by resetting it regularly in the normal software execution path, so if the normal path stops executing the system restarts.

Start by reading this primer App Note: [Getting Started with GPIO](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/Appnotes/90003229A.pdf)

First of all, you have misunderstood the function of the GPIO registers. `PORTB.IN` reads the *input states* of the PORTB pins that are configured as input.  It is *read-only* so:

```
PORTB.IN=0x04; // PB2 as input
```

has no effect and certainly does not configure the pin as an input.  That is done by `DDR`, so:

```
PORTB.DIR=0x09; // PB0 and PB3 output
```

sets PB0 and PB3 as outputs, and anything that is not an output is an input - so PB2 is an input by virtue of this line.

Now if you do as I recommend and use the internal pull-up for PB2, you must enable that in the `PIN2CTRL` register:

```
PORTB.PIN2CTRL = 0x08 ; // PULLUPEN
```

Incidentally there are symbols defined for all thse bits so you should be able to write:

```
PORTB.PIN2CTRL = PORT_PULLUPEN_bm ;
```

which also makes the comment unnecessary.

The registers `OUTSET` and `OUTCLR`, set (logic 1/high) and clear (logic 0/low) respectively.  The pins to be set/clear are determined by a *bit mask* passed in.  As such:

```
PORTB.OUTCLR=0x00; // Green
```

does nothing, it sets *no pins* to the low state.  To set the red LED (I am assuming PB3) off and the green LED (PB0) on:

```
PORTB.OUTCLR = PIN3_bm ;
PORTB.OUTSET = PIN0_bm ;
```

Now, your test of `PORTB.IN` as if it were Boolean will work in this case because you have only one input. But if you have more than one input, it will not distinguish between then, and it is a bad habit in any case to use an integer expression as if it were Boolean.  You should explicitly test the state of PB2:

```
    // If PB2 is low (GND wire connected)
    if( (PORTB.IN & PIN2_bm) == 0 )
    {
        PORTB.OUTSET = PIN3_bm ; // red on
    }
    else
    {
        PORTB.OUTCLR = PIN3_bm ; // red off
    }
```

The purpose of a watchdog timer is to reset the processor if the software fails to operate normally.  You set the timeout, then you need to reset it regularly in the code to prevent a reset.  It is not a general purpose you would use for a delay.  For that you would use a hardware timer. Unfortunately it gets a little complex; for your board running at 24MHz, the maximum timer period for the 16 bit TIMER1 is about 2.8 seconds. For more flexibility you would normally implement a timer interrupt to count a number of *smaller* periods and count the number of times the timer reloads.  For example:

```
volatile unsigned tick = 0 ;
ISR (TIMER1_OVF_vect)    // Timer1 ISR
{
    tick++ ;
}

void tickStart()
{
    
    TCCR1B = (1<<CS11) // Prescaler 24MHz / 8
    TCNT1 = 3000 ;   // 1 ms at 24MHz/8 
    TCCR1A = 0x00;
    TIMSK = (1 << TOIE1) ;   // Enable timer1 overflow interrupt(TOIE1)
    sei();        // Enable global interrupts
}

unsigned getTick()
{
    unsigned t = 0 ;
    do
    {
        t = tick ;
    } while( tick != t ) ;

    return t ;
}
```

Then for a 4 second delay while also monitoring P2 you might do:

```
// Wait 4 seconds or until PB2 disconnected
unsigned start = getTick() ;
while( getTick() - start < 4000 && 
       (PORTB.IN & PIN2_bm) != 0 ) 
{
    // waiting
}
```

Finally *comment your code*.  It will allow you to understand what you are trying to do and and when you post a question it will tell others what you are trying to do and it it will make your question simpler by having the explanation in-line with the code so it is clear not only what you want the code to do, but how you think it is doing it.

Putting it all together, the following is more plausible:

```
void fun_red( void )
{ 
    // Initialise I/O 
    PORTB.PIN2CTRL = PORT_PULLUPEN_bm ;
    PORTB.DIR = PIN0_bm | PIN3_bm ;
    
    PORTB.OUTSET = PIN0_bm ; // Green on

    for(;;) 
    {
        // Red off
        PORTB.OUTCLR = PIN3_bm ;
        
        // Wait for PB2 to be connected (to GND)
        while( (PORTB.IN & PIN2_bm) == 0 )
        {
            // waiting
        }
        
        // Red on
        PORTB.OUTSET = PIN3_bm ;
        
        // Wait 4 seconds or until PB2 disconnected
        unsigned start = getTick() ;
        while( getTick() - start < 4000 && 
               (PORTB.IN & PIN2_bm) != 0 ) 
        {
            // waiting
        } 
        
        // Wait for PB2 to be reconnected
        while( (PORTB.IN & PIN2_bm) != 0)
        {
            // waiting
        }
    }
}

int main( void )
{
    tickStart() ;
    fun_red() ;
}
```

Remember in this you connect PB2 to GND (0 volts) not not 5V/Vcc.  The requirements in the question are not entirely clear but what this will do (untested - I don't have the hardware) is:

- while PB2 is disconnected, the LED will be off,
- when PB2 is connected, the LED will be lit for 4 seconds or until PB2 is reconnected.

While it is not its intended purpose and it is not really useful for general purpose, because this requirement is very simple it is possible to us the watchdog timer to implement the desired behaviour as follows:

```
void fun_red()
{ 
    // Initialise I/O 
    PORTB.PIN2CTRL = PORT_PULLUPEN_bm ;
    PORTB.DIR = PIN0_bm | PIN3_bm ;
    
    // Green on
    PORTB.OUTSET = PIN0_bm ;
    
    // Red off
    PORTB.OUTCLR = PIN3_bm ;
     
    // Enable watchdog
    wdt_enable(WDTO_4S);
    
    for(;;)
    {
        // Maintain watchdog while waiting for 
        // PB2 to be connected (to GND)
        while( (PORTB.IN & PIN2_bm) == 0 )
        {
            wdt_reset() ;
        }
        
        // Red on
        PORTB.OUTSET = PIN3_bm ;
        
        // Maintain watchdog while waiting for 
        // PB2 to be disconnected (from GND)
        while( (PORTB.IN & PIN2_bm) != 0)
        {
            wdt_reset() ;
        }

        // Red off
        PORTB.OUTCLR = PIN3_bm ;

        // Wait for PB2 to be reconnected (to GND)
        // without maintaining watchdog.  Will reset after 4 seconds
        // if not reconnected.
        while( (PORTB.IN & PIN2_bm) != 0)
        {
            // do nothing
        }
    }
}
```

Here after PB2 is disconnected, the watchdog is not maintained, so that after 4 seconds a reset will occur and it with restart the program and wait for PB2 to be connected.  I think I should class such code as a "dirty-trick", not something to be considered normal or particularly useful.

Comment: The OP needs to read this and maybe you did too Clifford, it is an off the shelf board.  PB2 is as documented connected between PB2 and ground through a switch (normally open momentary SPST one would assume).   And it says there is no pull up you need to enable the pull up in the mcu.   Which means that PB2 is normally high (exact voltage value doesnt matter, reads as a 1 in the gpio) and when pressed reads as low.     The led is tied between vcc_target through a resistor to pb3, which means writing a 0 makes the led go on and a 1 makes it go off.

Comment: as written in the question and the answer it will simply mirror the push button.  If as at the end of the question, you want the led on for 4 seconds when the button is pressed, you need to do more work, and you do not want to use the WDT use some other timer.  or if you use the wdt then if button pressed (if pb2 is low) then turn the led on and go into an infinite loop that does not call wdt reset, AND set wdt for 4 seconds...

Comment: @old_timer  What documentation are you referencing?  I _did_ reference the [Curiosity Nano datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/AVR128DA48-Curiosity-Nano-UG-DS50002971A.pdf) and the on-board switch is on PC7, and LED on PC6.  Begs the question however why this code would not use both the on-board switch and the on-board LED - at least to avoid the need to understand the electronics.

Comment: I already stated the need to use the internal pull-up - I don't see your point - your comment repeats a large amount of my answer (perhaps _you_ might read _that_ ;-).  If you have an answer post one, if there is an issue with the _this_ answer be specific - I'll fix it (it was late).

Comment: I did miss the point about on for 4 seconds - even though that too was clarified (kind of) in the edit.  The OP code did not appear to indicate that, and the watchdog timer is clearly irrelevant.  Will fix.

Comment: @old_timer  4 second timer added.

Comment: @Clifford correct that what I want. in tickStart() all the member are variables e.g these are variable so I need to declare it like int TCCR1B,etc

Comment: `TCCR1B` etc. should be in one of the system headers that you have included.  Without a link to the documentation for the library you are using , I cannot be sure.  Possibly you can write something like` TCCR1B.CS11 = 1` instead of  ` TCCR1B = (1<<CS11)`.  Whatever the library/header documentation states.

Comment: There is a way you can use the watchdog to do this, but I wouldn't recommend it.  I will add it shortly in any case for completeness.

Comment: Watchdog timer solution added (use advisedly).

Comment: Resource for the timer interrupt stuff:  https://exploreembedded.com/wiki/AVR_Timer_Interrupts

Comment: Re: my suggestion: _"Possibly you can write something like` TCCR1B.CS11 = 1`"_ you can't.  At least not with [avr-libc](https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/index.html) which you appear to be using.  That would require a structure with bitfield members.  However they are all standard SFR definitions included via avr/io.h

Comment: Added missing `return t;` in `getTick()`.

Comment: @Clifford thank you this thing help me alot. one more question. the PB2 i check it's 3V not 5V when I removed the wire from the controller still the light didn't off. the red on.

Comment: @Clifford if I don't look to timer or watchdog etc. just two if else statement. if voltage on PB2 is high red on ,, green off. and if low green on ,, red off

Comment: @Clifford Hi thank you I solve the problem

Comment: @Studyonly  Well that was what I'd written before.  The timer was added because your question clearly stated _"turn red light off after every 4 sec"_.  You need to fix the question if that is not actually required - the timer solution was the major part of the work ion this answer, so you appear to have wasted my time.

Comment: @Clifford it was written and I want that. and it worked as I want. but it was little problem with the if statement but I fixed it

Comment: @Studyonly : As you can see there was much that was wrong with your code.  The problem you knew about an all those mentioned in this answer.  I apologies if that information was not required, but it matches the breadth of your question; if you wanted _less_ you should have been more specific.  If you think there was just a "little problem" with the code, you are wrong.  Most of it was nonsense.  Anyway SO is not a discussion forum; it is not normal to post a "thank you note"; if the answer solved your problem, you should  mark it "accepted".

Comment: @Clifford with this lot of my question clear. basically when the program start both LED Blink for 4 sec. after that it should off and wait for the input. I'm using watchdog if the state of a program didn't change for 30 sec mean no input rest it and blink both LED again. something like this. but I was confuse with watchdog